# codeigniter empty session navigation template

Tags: php, codeigniter, view, controller

I have this code on a navigation template.

```
 <a href="<?php  
                    if(!empty($session)){
                    echo site_url('/pages/view/profile');
                    }else{
                    echo site_url('/pages/view/login'); }?>">

                    <?php if(!empty($session['username'])){ echo 'Welcome '.$session['username'];}else{ echo 'Account'; }?></a>
```

I already declared `$session = $this->session->userdata();` inside the navigation container.

It's really simple. I just wanted the Account Link to change to "Welcome " if a user is logged hence check if `$session['username']` is empty or not. This part works. The first part though, it's quite troublesome.

I wanted it to link to 2 different views, I have a view function on my pages controller that handles views.

IF a user is logged in hence `!empty($session)` it will redirect to the profile view, if not, it will redirect to log in view.

The problem is that, it always redirects to profile view even when i deleted the cookies of my browser(i still havent gotten around to doing a logout function so i opted to just delete the cookies as a means of log out to check my code). It should redirect me to my log in page but will still redirect me to my profile page.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: How to Ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it. Even when i deleted cookies, i printed the $session and it displayed Last_regenerate and some value. So i guess it meant that when i inputted `!empty($session)` it always returned false. Thus the $session array wasn't empty the whole time.

So instead of `!empty($session)` i just used `!empty($session['username'];`.